# How to create a text file and a JSON with laravel 4 framework?

Tags: php, json, file, laravel, frameworks

#### Hello!, the question might be simple, but i couldn't find the answer.

i want to create a **.txt file** with **laravel 4** and *upload it to my server* like PHP does, and also
i need to create a **JSON file** with **laravel 4** and upload it to my server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what have your tired so far? do you googled it?

Comment: until now i can't find anything that solve my problem, the CodeIgniter Framework, let you do that, but the librarie for zipping and unzipping .zip files of laravel looks better then CondeIgniter zip and unzip Libraries, that's why i wanna use Laravel

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To use the filesystem of Laravel, you should access it through the `File` Facade.

**Create a new file:**

```
//Usage
File::put($path,$contents);
//Example
File::put('web/text/mytextdocument.txt','John Doe');
```

**Delete a file:**

```
//Usage
File::delete(string|array $paths)
//Example
File::delete('web/text/mytextdocument.txt');
```

The complete documentation on all available methods is found here:
https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html